# Validation comes from configuration in database - add to Model - add to ViewModel at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

Using Entity Framework (Code First):

Each customer has a different set of requirements for example certain fields are required.

Or Max Min and so on.

So from configuration I am thinking finding a way to inject "Data Annotations" e.g. IsRequired and MaxLength into both the Model (using EntityTypeConfiguration  +  Fluent API?) used by the Repositories / Services and the ViewModels for MVC.

Obviously the view models may have extra validations.

For the MVC I override GetValidators in DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider?

Does this make sense?

If it does. I expect I have to inject the Configurations into the modelbuilder before the tables even necessarily exist!!?

Comment: do you have a set number of customers? or do you plan to design this for unlimited number of customers and thereby an unlimited number of permutations?

Comment: I would take a look on FluentValidation for this kind of needs. http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Comment: @DaveA unlimited number of customers and permutations?

Comment: If the permutations are unlimited, I wouldn't approach it from a Model Binding perspective. I would create the JQuery Validation dynamically upon rendering.

Comment: EF should take care of validation if you set max length, required etc. in OnModelCreating when you do SaveChanges. Obviously you will need to the show errors (if any) to the client. You can also validate on demand using DbContext.GetValidationErrors()